# Convert JSON data to querystring in C# GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, get, query-string

What is the best way to convert a JSON object into query strings to append to a GET URL? The POST is straightforward and gets read by my web API backend.

`{Name: 'Mike' } = ?Name=Mike`

```cs
private static string MakeRequest(HttpWebRequest req, string data)
{
    try
    {
        if (req.Method == Verbs.POST.ToString() || req.Method == Verbs.PUT.ToString() || req.Method == Verbs.DELETE.ToString())
        {
            var encodedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            req.ContentLength = encodedData.Length;
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.GetRequestStream().Write(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length);
        }

        using (var response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        if(we.Response == null)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Errors = new List<ApiError> { new ApiError(11, "API is currently unavailable") }});
        }

        using (var response = we.Response as HttpWebResponse)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the json object is flat as in your example, then

```
string json = @"{
    ""name"": ""charlie"",
    ""num"": 123
}";

var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var query = String.Join("&",
                jObj.Children().Cast<JProperty>()
                .Select(jp=>jp.Name + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(jp.Value.ToString())));
```

query would be `name=charlie&num=123`

Comment: Would this handle an array Includes=["Assets","Prices"]

Comment: This is very clever sir! I like your mustache as well.

Comment: This will not handle arrays correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I make this code to run in .Net Core:

```
public static string JsonToQuery(this string jsonQuery)
    {
        string str = "?";
        str += jsonQuery.Replace(":", "=").Replace("{","").
                    Replace("}", "").Replace(",","&").
                        Replace("\"", "");
        return str;
    }
```

Example:

```
var _baseURI = "http://www.example.com/";
var endPoint = "myendpoint";
ExampleObjectModel requestModel = new ExampleObjectModel();
var requestModelJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel);
var url = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _baseURI, endPoint, requestModelJson.JsonToQuery());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, work all object, in deep

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetQueryString(this object obj, string prefix = "")
    {
        var query = "";
        try
        {
            var vQueryString = (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));

            var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(vQueryString);
            query = String.Join("&",
               jObj.Children().Cast<JProperty>()
               .Select(jp =>
               {
                   if (jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                   {
                       var count = 0;
                       var arrValue = String.Join("&", jp.Value.ToList().Select<JToken, string>(p =>
                       {
                           var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(p.ToString()).GetQueryString(jp.Name + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("[") + count++ + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("]"));
                           return tmp;
                       }));
                       return arrValue;
                   }
                   else
                       return (prefix.Length > 0 ? prefix + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("[") + jp.Name + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("]") : jp.Name) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(jp.Value.ToString());
               }
               )) ?? "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

To use: SomeObject.GetQueryString();

Answer (score 0):

if your object(Entity) have a Children like this Entity :

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child childs { get; set; } = new Child();
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int? PageSize { get; set; }
}    
public class Child 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your Can Use This Code For Build Query:
First Convert You Enrity Model To JObject
And Call This Method :

```
        public static string GetQueryString(this JObject jObj)
    {
        return String.Join("&",
             jObj.Children().Cast<JProperty>()
             .Select(jp =>
             {
                 if (jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                 {
                     var arrValue = String.Join("&",
                     jObj.Values().Children().Cast<JProperty>()
                     .Select(jp => jp.Path + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(jp.Value.ToString())));
                     return arrValue;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     var arrValue = String.Join("&", jp.Name + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(jp.Value.ToString()));
                     return arrValue;
                 }
             }
             )) ?? "";
    }
```

Your Can Get Like This QueryString :

```
childs.Id=1&childs.Name="Test"&PageIndex=1&PageSize=1
```