# How to pass collection to GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I've this GET method in my MVC Web Api:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeeByJobTitle(List<string> jobTitles)
{
    var employeeByJobTitle = from e in db.Employee
                             where jobTitles.Contains(e.JobTitle)
                             select e;
    return db.Employee;
}
```

because I need to get a set of employees by job titles. So if I want all employees with job Title in "Production Technician - WC60" and "Production Supervisor - WC60", I need to call this URI

> http://localhost:60054/api/Employee/GetEmployeeByJobTitles/?jobTitles[0]=%22Production%20Technician%20-%20WC60%22&jobTitles[1]=%22Production%20Supervisor%20-%20WC60%22

As you can see the query string is huge and complex. Now, I need to call this method from a client console using `HttpClient` class from `Web.API.Client.Libraries`. Is there an easy way to create a method builting the above query string starting from the object:

```
var jobTitles = new List<string>
{
    "Production Technician - WC60",
    "Production Supervisor - WC60"
};
```

Something like

```
string BuiltUriFromObject(List<string> jobTitles){};
```

Comment: Do you have to use a GET?  With complex data, a POST would be better.

Comment: With regards to your question, you'd probably be better served passing a JSON object in as the parameter, then parsing it in the handler.  I'd suggest creating a container for that JSON object and using that as the parameter.

Comment: With regards to the code you posted, your method returns the entire Employee table; is that really what you want?  Also, you might get "Context has been disposed" exceptions with this approach; it would probably be better to materialize the resultset and return an IEnumerable<EmployeDto>, that way you can sanitize the output and mitigate the risk of sending PII over the wire.  Just give the requestor what they need, not more.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I'm pretty new to Web Api. I've thought to use a POST request but is it correct to use a POST request in order to get a list of object? I still had to call my Web Api method `GetEmployeeByJobTitles` but it would perform a POST action. I'm pretty confuse. Can you help me?

Comment: So @K_foxer9 I would first convert  `List<string> jobTitles = ... ` in a json object and then using this string to compose the uri with something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610585/convert-json-data-to-querystring-in-c-sharp-get-request

Comment: The JSON approach would use a DTO  similar to the following: `public class MyDto {public List<string> Query;}`.  The api endpoint would start with `public IEnumerable<string> Get(string stuff) { var names = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDto>(stuff);` The query string would be `localhost:50237/api/values?stuff={'Query':['item1','item2']}`

Answer (score 2):

This situation suits the [FromUri attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri) which will create the specified model from the querystring.

Declare the controller like this

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetEmployeeByJobTitle([FromUri]string[] jobTitles)
{
    var employeeByJobTitle = from e in db.Employee
                             where jobTitles.Contains(e.JobTitle)
                             select e;
    return Ok(employeeByJobTitle.ToArray());
}
```

Call this method by adding as many titles you like but declare all titles to the same parameter name `jobTitles="CIO"&jobTitles="CTO"` then the FromUri will create a list with `List<string>{"CIO", "CTO"}`.

In your case, something like this

```
api/Employee?jobTitles=%22Production%20Technician%20-%20WC60%22&jobTitles=%22Production%20Supervisor%20-%20WC60%22
```