# Nested Query String Encoder/Decoder c#

Tags: c#, .net, flurl

**Brief**

I'm trying to call some API endpoints who use nested query strings in the GET calls

**Issue**

Trying not to reinvent the wheel, I'm looking for a library that is able to convert a nested object into query string parameters

**Example**

Given the object:

`{'searchCriteria':{'filterGroups':[{'filters':[{'field':'entity_id','value':"1",'condition_type':'eq'}]}]}}`

Results into a URL on the likes of: [http://example.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=5325](http://example.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=entity_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D=eq&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=5325)

or, when expanded:

```
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=5325
```

**Resources**

Equivalent nodejs library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

**Recap**

How do you serialise/deserialise a nested query string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON data to querystring in C# GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610585/convert-json-data-to-querystring-in-c-sharp-get-request)

Comment: @YegorAndrosov not exactly. that's only going one level deep and it's not generic

Comment: this article looks like what you need https://geeklearning.io/serialize-an-object-to-an-url-encoded-string-in-csharp/

Comment: I can say that Flurl doesn't do this out of the box, and I think it'll be hard to find something that does because AFAIK there's no widely agreed upon best practice for stringifying a nested object in a query string. I'd even argue it's poor API design, but I'm guessing you have no control over that.

Comment: @ToddMenier it's the first time I come across something like this and I agree it's not pretty - it's the old api for magento. I'll probably look into the graphql api instead, luckily it does have support for it.